# TFS 2010 build agent: is it possible to get the latest code from tfs proxy?

Tags: build, agent

we're looking to implement TFS 2010 for our teams which are split up at onshore and offshore. we've TFS Proxy in plan for the offshore team, with the TFS setup at onshore.
i know that when the clients at offshore checkout their code, it will be from the proxy whereas the webservices call will be directly on the app tier.
we will also have build machines at offshore & onshore. the onshore build machine can get the latest code version from the app tier, and that is just fine. my question is when the build machine at offshore requests a get latest, will it get the code directly from the app tier at onshore or is there a provision where the files can be got from the tfs proxy?

any help with this is going to be of much help. thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**MSDN: Configure Team Foundation Build Service to Use Team Foundation Server Proxy**
You can configure Team Foundation Build Service to retrieve files from Team Foundation Server Proxy by modifying a registry entry on the server that is running Team Foundation Build Service. If you modify this entry,  Team Foundation Build Service at the remote site can work with version control from the proxy's cache.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716770.aspx

Comment: hey thank you very much!!! i've been on msdn for days now & somehow couldnt find this article!!! cheers!!!